# android camera object always a null pointer

Tags: android, surfaceview, video-capture, android-mediarecorder, null-pointer

I call this method and it gives me a camera object is a null pointer on the recorder.setCamera(this.camera) call

```
    private void initRecorder()
{
    if(camera == null)
    {
       camera = Camera.open();
       camera.unlock();
    }
    recorder.setCamera(this.camera);
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    recorder.setVideoFrameRate(60);

    CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(cameraInfo.facing,CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
    String fileName = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    recorder.setOutputFile(varPtr.DefaultStorageDir + fileName  + ".mp4");
    recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
    //recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
}
```

it is called from my onSurfaceCreated function seen here

```
 @Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "surfaceCreated");
    initRecorder();

}
```

I have this in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.back" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

I even tried using this code which should definitely work because I have selected in my avd settings to emulate both the front and back cameras so they are emulated. I even tested the emulator's default camera app and the video and still camera work on it.

```
 private Camera openFrontFacingCamera()
{
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("WTF", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return cam;
}
```

please if anyone is experienced with android help! I'm really starting to absolutely despise developing for android.

Comment: Post your LogCat... run trough the Debugger and look what exactly is null. For me it Looks like your `recorder` isn't initialized! That's maybe the reason why this line throws a NPE. Because regarding to the `docs` if `camera.open()` Fails, it would cause a `RuntimeError`.. so Recorder is not initialized is the only Logical reason to me from what you have posted... But i can't say more without your LogCat and your full code which has to do with this NPE..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try it even without your `LogCat` and additional Code from your side.

For me it Looks like your `recorder` isn't initialized. That's why it throws a NPE at this line.

Make sure you are initializing `recorder` before Setting a `CameraObject` to `recorder`.

Because regarding to the `docs`:

`RuntimeException 
if opening the camera fails (for example, if the camera is in use by another process or device policy manager has disabled the camera).`

so your `camera-object`should be valid... so the only Logical answere is your `recorder` isn't initialized.

Read more here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int)

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks I got the camera to not be null but now recorder.start() gives me an illegal state exception everytime for no reason. here is the logcat

Comment: start called in an invalid state: 4
12-30 11:04:54.510    1480-1480/com.L33TRUS.shite D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-30 11:04:54.510    1480-1480/com.L33TRUS.shite W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-30 11:04:54.743    1480-1480/com.L33TRUS.shite E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
            at l33trus.com.shite.Fragments.VideoCapture.onClick(VideoCapture.java:396)

Comment: @user3188402 this is another Problem. Please mark my answere as accepted as it was the solution to your original issue and open a new one if necessary. But first, please read trough this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html. Look at the very top. Invalid state means often that your Recorder isn't prepared correctly. In the link they tell you how to set up correctly. If you got Problems anyway even with the link. open a new question please